# Why does my while loop seems to always be false

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to make my php code to show entries from my mysql database. I wanted to make it automatic in a sense that i wouldn't need to print the tables manually instead they would be printed according to an alogrythm, but it doesn't work like intended.

I've tried different ways of setting up the table but none of them worked, the furthest I got was to print one entry from the table, and spitting errors after it.

```
$base = $_POST["base"];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","login","pass") or die("Impossible to connect to the database!");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database")or die("Impossible to download the database!");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $base";
$mysqli_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $base";
$set1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);
$colu = array();
while($db = mysqli_fetch_row($set1)){
  $colu[] = $db[0]; }
$columns=implode("<br/>",$colu);
echo "<TABLE BORDER=1>";
echo "<TR><TH>$colu[0]</TH><TH>$colu[1]</TH><TH>$colu[2]</TH><TH>$colu[3]</TH><TH>$colu[4]</TH><TH>$colu[5]</TH></TR>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($set1)) {
$colu[0] = $row["echo $colu[0]"];
$colu[1] = $row["echo $colu[1]"];
$colu[2] = $row["echo $colu[2]"];
$colu[3] = $row["echo $colu[3]"];
$colu[4] = $row["echo $colu[4]"];
$colu[5] = $row["echo $colu[5]"];
echo "<TR><TD>$colu[0]</TD><TD>$colu[1]</TD><TD>$colu[2]</TD><TD>$colu[3]</TD><TD>$colu[4]</TD><TD>$colu[5]</TD></TR>";}

echo "</TABLE>";
mysqli_free_result($mysqli_result);
mysqli_close($connection); ?>
```

the $_POST[$base]; part works, Im guessing the issue is in the while loop as it doesnt complete once, and I'm lost as to why it doesnt want to work.

Comment: I think that in your second loop `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($set1)) {`, you should be using `$mysqli_result` rather than `$set1`.  Also not sure what your trying to do with `$row["echo $colu[0]"];`

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Your fetching the mysql result as rows and afterwards as array? And your $colu[0] = $row["echo $colu[0]"]; is just not working. You shouldn't use the same variable for addressing and as storage for your result. Although the echo is unneccessary and won't work at all..

Comment: Okay, I just realized what was wrong, the
$colu[0] = $row["echo $colu[0]"];
should look like 
$colum[0] = $row["$colu[0]"];
and the table printing loop should be changed accordingly. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Now it works :)

Comment: Your choice of variable names leaves a lot to be desired.  Some examples `$db = mysqli_fetch_row($set1)`  Just in this you have `$db` for rows (you previously used DB too), and `$set1` whatever that stands for.  In either case I can't tell what this info is without looking at the code and possibly outputting it.  You have `$colu` used 2x, without resetting it between uses. etc...   This `$row["echo $colu[0]"];`  is probably  `$row["echo Array"]`

Comment: This is really bad `$base = $_POST["base"]` and then `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $base";`.  This is a huge security issue for SQLInjection.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems in you script. If you want to fetch columns as heading and the content for the table body you are using the wrong result sets.

```
// next line make it possible to do sql insertion, and what if $base has no input?
$base = $_POST["base"];
// the die will never be reached
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","login","pass") or die("Impossible to connect to the database!");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database")or die("Impossible to download the database!");
// where is this query for?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $base";
// where is this result being used
$mysqli_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $base";
$set1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);
$colu = [];
// what if the table order chages? Best to use mysqli_fetch_assoc
while($db = mysqli_fetch_row($set1)){
    $colu[] = $db[0]; 
}
// where do you use $comumns?
$columns = implode("<br/>", $colu);

echo "<TABLE BORDER=1>";
echo "<TR><TH>$colu[0]</TH><TH>$colu[1]</TH><TH>$colu[2]</TH><TH>$colu[3]</TH><TH>$colu[4]</TH><TH>$colu[5]</TH></TR>";
// you already fetched all record from set1
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($set1)) {
    $colu[0] = $row["echo $colu[0]"];
    $colu[1] = $row["echo $colu[1]"];
    $colu[2] = $row["echo $colu[2]"];
    $colu[3] = $row["echo $colu[3]"];
    $colu[4] = $row["echo $colu[4]"];
    $colu[5] = $row["echo $colu[5]"];
    echo "<TR><TD>$colu[0]</TD><TD>$colu[1]</TD><TD>$colu[2]</TD><TD>$colu[3]</TD><TD>$colu[4]</TD><TD>$colu[5]</TD></TR>";
}

echo "</TABLE>";
mysqli_free_result($mysqli_result);
mysqli_close($connection); ?>
```

Comment: 1. You should explain what you've actually changed and how it solves the issue. 2. The above still contains issues. For example, `$row["echo $colu[0]"]` isn't really the proper way to use the result of `$colu[0]` as array key. You've also kept the biggest problem of all in there, the risk of SQL injections.

Comment: I agree, the code has to many faults in it. I pointed out some to help him on.

Answer (score 0):

This biggest issue you have right now is this:

```
$base = $_POST["base"]
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $base";
$sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $base";
```

This is a huge SQL Injection vulnerability, even if they pass just an empty string to this it's all bad.  For example that would result in a query error and depending on your settings on the server and for error reporting, you may expose quite a bit of info.  Just one example is a stack trace could contain DB passwords etc.

Instead of directly using user input make a whitelist like this:

```
$tables = ['user', 'user_meta', 'states']; //etc

$base =  !empty($_POST["base"]) && false !== ($index = array_search($_POST["base"], $tables)) ? $tables[$index] : false;

if(!$base) die('Unknown table '.$_POST["base"]);
```

This way you are only using data you know the value of.

**Variable reuse**

Other then that, your variable names are causing a bunch of "code confusion".  This is what happens if you have to generic of a variable name.  Some examples:

```
   $db = mysqli_select_db(...)
   while($db = mysqli_fetch_row($set1)){  //overwriting db
     ...
   }
   //....................
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($set1)) {
     $colu[0] = $row["echo $colu[0]"]; //overwriting $colu
```

This last one is also wrong because the row key will be something like:

```
   $colu[0] = $row["echo name"];
```

Or something with a column name. Because you are re-using this variable ("variable confusion" ) on the next loop it will be the value of `$row["echo $colu[0]"];` which will get put back into that.  So lets assume this is correct without the `echo` and will use `Name` as the value.

```
//loop 1
   $colu[0] = 'name';
   $row['name'] = 'Tom';
   //result 
   $colu[0] = 'Tom'

//loop 2
   $colu[0] = 'Tom';
   $row['Tom']  doesn't exist.
   //result 
   $colu[0] = null; //undefined index warning
```

**Cursor Reuse**

You are also reusing the DB cursor `$set1` and looping over it 2 times.  I'm not sure about MySqli, but PDO won't allow you to do that.  This is probably why the second loop is failing.  I believe the second one should be `$mysqli_result`.  It's a bit confusing because you do both queries then loop though one then the other.  Instead of doing a query, looping through it. Then doing the other, and looping though that.

Instead you can do something like this:

```
//you can even query the DB for the table names
$tables = ['user', 'user_meta', 'states']; //etc

$base =  !empty($_POST["base"]) && false !== ($index = array_search($_POST["base"], $tables)) ? $tables[$index] : false;

if(!$base) die('Unknown table '.$_POST["base"]);

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","login","pass") or die("Impossible to connect to the database!");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database")or die("Impossible to download the database!");

//---------query for the columns
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$base`";
$mysqli_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$columns = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($mysqli_result)){
    $columns[] = $row[0]; 
}

//---------query for the data
//use the column result in the select part of query, because the column names
//come from the DB they are safe to use.
$sql = "SELECT `".implode('`,`', $columns)."` FROM `$base`"; //reuse sql (no longer needed)

$mysqli_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); //reuse results (no longer needed)

//fetch all data as assoc array. because we tied it to the results 
//of the first query, the column names.  We no longer need to map it.
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

///output table and headers

echo "<table>";
   echo "<thead>";
      echo "<tr>";
      //we can just loop over the columns and put them in the table head
      foreach($columns as $key ){
          echo "<th>$key</th>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
   echo "</thead>";
   echo "<tbody>";

   //loop over each row of data
   foreach($data as $row){
      echo "<tr>";

      //loop over each "correlated" column
      foreach($columns as $key ){
         echo "<td>{$row[$key]}</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";  
   }
   echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

**BONUS** For getting the table names from the DB:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `TABLE_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE "'.$database.'"';
$mysqli_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$tables = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli_result, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Hope that makes sense.